# Please explain the "IPC Security" paragraph in the Electron tutorial

Tags: electron

The page titled [Using Preload Scripts](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-preload) in the Electron documentation says,

> **IPC SECURITY**
> Notice how we wrap the `ipcRenderer.invoke('ping')` call in a helper function rather than expose the `ipcRenderer` module directly via context bridge. You **never** want to directly expose the entire `ipcRenderer` module via preload. This would give your renderer the ability to send arbitrary IPC messages to the main process, which becomes a powerful attack vector for malicious code.

What is the threat being described here?

Because when I write an Electron application then it's me who writes both, the main process and the renderer -- why then must the renderer be less privileged than the main process?

What foreign (potentially malicious) code, if any, is running in the renderer and not in the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The renderer process is less privileged to reduce [RCE](https://blog.devsecurity.eu/en/blog/joplin-electron-rce), XSS, or other attacks that might cause damage to your underlying system that's running the Electron application. This is most-applicable to apps that you distribute to others, where you can't trust how the user will interact with your application. Outside of malicious actors interacting with your app, I can't say the risk is 0 (solely because there might be *something* that could happen), but it's probably very small.

Besides focusing on the security benefits of using IPC and the renderer/main process, in my opinion it's a good separation of concerns and sets up your app to be in a place to distribute it if you decide to do so in the future.

I wrote about a [history of Electron](https://www.debugandrelease.com/the-ultimate-electron-guide/) as well as how IPC works and how the framework changed to *now* emphasize/promote IPC (in case that's something you want to read).

Comment: I understand it in the Chrome web browser, where the end-user is loading web sites and scripts from 3rd parties. I don't understand it when I'm writing an Electron desktop app, in which I write the code that's loaded into the render. Is there some threat I should be aware of? Or is this threat applicable only when the render is loading scripts from 3rd-party web sites?

Comment: @ChrisW The threat is most (likely only) applicable when the renderer is loading scripts from 3rd party websites or is used by outside users, that is where RCE, XSS or other attacks might happen.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and for the link to your article in your answer. Your article is a clear explanation of context isolation, and I'll look into sandboxing too. I added [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73515953/49942) to reference some security guidelines that I found via something that your article linked to.

Answer (score 1):

[reZach's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73515506/49942) links to an article:

- [The ultimate Electron guide](https://www.debugandrelease.com/the-ultimate-electron-guide/)

That includes this paragraph:

> You see, sticking Node in the renderer process opens up our applications to [RCE](https://blog.devsecurity.eu/en/blog/joplin-electron-rce) (remote code execution) attacks. Through unique ways, a motivated individual can open up the developer tools on your Electron app (remember, the window is simply a Chromium browser), find the reference to fs, and boom - there goes all of your files.

The linked article is *Joplin ElectronJS based Client: from XSS to RCE* by Jaroslav Lobačevski begins:

> One day I was reading the master’s thesis [“Analysis of Electron-Based Applications…”](https://digi.lib.ttu.ee/i/file.php?DLID=9890&t=1) by Silvia Väli. She basically applied the [auditing checklist](https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-17/thursday/us-17-Carettoni-Electronegativity-A-Study-Of-Electron-Security-wp.pdf) by Luca Carettoni, searched GitHub projects for some interesting keywords and then manually reviewed and tested for vulnerabilities. The hypothesis of her thesis was that since Electron framework has many insecure defaults there must be significant number of vulnerable applications. It appeared to be true and she scored a bunch of nice CVEs.
>
> Personally I find vulnerabilities in Electron based applications interesting because of the lack of process isolation, that can easily lead from a “simple” XSS to Code Execution on the running machine.

That auditing checklist is *Electron Security Checklist
A guide for developers and auditors* from 2017 on `blackhat.com`.

Its first two checklist items include,

> - Disable nodeIntegration for untrusted origins
> - Use sandbox for untrusted origins

In summary "untrusted origins" seems to confirm [reZach's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73511879/please-explain-the-ipc-security-paragraph-in-the-electron-tutorial/73515506?noredirect=1#comment129822440_73515506):

> The threat is most (likely only) applicable when the renderer is loading scripts from 3rd party websites or is used by outside users, that is where RCE, XSS or other attacks might happen.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you may have an XSS vulnerability in the renderer, like if you don't escape user input or data from an external source.

For example, if, for any reason, you have an `eval` call starting from the text of an HTML `input` that is not checked in any way, then what explained in the paragraph you shared would avoid unexpected IPC messages to the main process that may compromise your application security.